# How many different kinds of hands can appear in a single Texas Hold 'em game?

Tags: cards, poker

[Texas Hold 'em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em) is a form of poker where each player has 2 "pocket" cards, which they combine with 3 (or more) community cards from a pool of 5 to form their hand, which are then scored under poker ranks.

Poker cards are scored on the following hands, from best to worst.

- Straight flush (5 consecutive cards of the same suit)
- Four-of-a-kind (4 cards of the same rank, and one other card)
- Full House (3 cards of the same rank, and 2 cards of another rank)
- Flush (5 cards of the same suit, not consecutive)
- Straight (5 consecutive cards, not suited)
- Three of a Kind (3 cards of the same rank, 2 cards of other different ranks)
- Two pair (2 cards of the same rank, 2 cards of another rank, and 1 card of yet another rank)
- One pair (2 cards of the same rank, 3 cards of different other ranks)
- High Card (5 cards of different ranks, neither suited nor consecutive)

For the purposes of this puzzle:

- Players are required to select the highest possible hand. If they have 2 spades as their pocket and there are 3 spades in the community cards, they cannot form any hand worse than a flush.
- All hands of the same type are equivalent. E.g. all straight flushes are treated as the same hand, even ace-high royal flushes.

Is it possible to form a set of community cards and 9 sets of pocket cards so that all 9 kinds of scoring hands are formed? If not, what is the maximum number of different kinds of hands that can be formed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the maximum number of different hands is 7

> Because 4 of a kind requires a pair on board, which eliminates High Card, and requires both of the other two available cards of that value, eliminating Three of a Kind. (An on board pair turns any other valued triplet into a Full House)

Here is one such example:

> Clockwise Straight Flush, Flush, Straight, Four of a Kind, Full House, Two Pair, Pair
>  [image: Hold' Em Hand]

Comment: Also, if you try leaving out the quads, the full house still requires a paired board, making "high card" impossible, so you can't get to 8 that way either.

Comment: One can easily prove that 8 is not possible. First, if the board is not paired, then neither 4 of a kind nor full house can be achieved. Second, if the board is paired, one can't make high card and only one of 3 of a kind and 4 of a kind can be achieved. Finally, if the board contains either 2 pair or 3 of a kind then both single pair and high card can't be achieved.